# geometry node random object placement index random value question

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

[image]

This is the geometry node I connected to.
[image]

In addition to cones, there are several objects such as spheres in the collection.

There is no problem in 3.0, but only cone is repeated in 3.2 and 3.4 versions.

In 3.0, until the index node is connected to the attribute statistic node, only the cone is repeated, but when the index node is connected, another object is created.

However, in versions 3.2 and 3.4, even if the index is connected, only the cone is repeated. Why is this happening?
[image]

If i increase the min value of the random value, another object is also created, but in the video I referenced, he did not touch the min value.

Question 1. Why is there a difference between 3.0 and 3.2, 3.4 results?

Question 2. Is this node that was created to place objects in a collection in a random order?

Question 3. Is it the right way to raise the min value of the random value node and place it randomly? He didn't touch the min value, so I'm worried if I can touch this value.

Question 4. Please let me know if there is any other way to implement it in version 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is not working properly because the `Attribute Statistic` node is querying the `Collection Info` in the *Point* domain. Since there are no points in that geometry (because they're all instances), the result ends up being $0$. The random value between $0$ and $0$ is $0$, so it only picks the first instance—the one with *Index* $0$.

Set it to the *Instance* domain and it should work as you expect:

[image]<sub>*You could also use a [ Domain Size—Instances > Subtract—1 ] setup to get the same highest index number to feed the Random Value—Max socket.*</sub>

If so, why did it work for Blender 3.0? Because back then the `Attribute Statistic` node did not yet support the *Instance* domain separately and instances were handled by the *Point* domain:

[image]<sub>*Blender 3.0.1: There's no "Instance" domain option in the dropdown yet.*</sub>

Comment: Is it the same result if I connect domain and subtract instead of index, attribute, and random? 
Is it right to connect subtract to the instance index of instance on points?
In that case, only the same object repeats.

Comment: @loejua2332 Sorry about not being clearer. $Instance Count-1$ would give you the highest index number as well, that's what I meant. You need to subtract $1$ because index numbers begin with $0$. Updated the answer with a gif showing the two situations.

Comment: thank you very much Kuboå